# Linear transformation of matrices 2x2 case with respect a different basis other than the standard

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $$T:{M_{2x2}} \to {M_{2x2}}$$ be defined as $$T(A) = \left( {\matrix{ 2 & 1 \cr 1 & 2 \cr   } } \right)A - A\left( {\matrix{ 2 & 1 \cr 1 & 2 \cr   } } \right)$$

Find the matrix of T with respect to the basis ${B}$  $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

I think I have an idea how to do this. Can you guys give me a hint as to how to to start this thing? Like what will the first column of the transformation look like?

Comment: See my answer to your other question. What is $T \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? How do you write this in terms of the given basis? That will be the first column of $Mat(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to see how those basis elements transform under $T$. I will do it for the first one.

$$T\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This can be written as a linear combination of the other basis elements which I label $a,b,c,d$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=-b+2a+2c+2d$$

Representing those basis elements by the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^4$ we obtain the first column:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ -1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I think you did it for the second column not the first?

Comment: I did the first one, I just wrote the wrong matrix at first. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: And I did another calculation error that I fixed.

Comment: Haha yeah, I was wondering that too.